# Finding mostly likely waiting time, given mean

Tags: probability, statistics

I have come across a statistics question which I couldn't find a solution to.

Q: What is the most likely waiting time for students if the average waiting time in cafeteria for lunch is 10 minutes?

It seems there's a queue to get a lunch box and the mean is 10 minutes. The questions asks <10 mins vs >10 mins.

So here we only have the mean. So how would you approach with only 1 known?

Thanks

Comment: you need additional information about the distribution of the waiting times

Comment: I think the question is asking to make some assumptions as well (e.g. if it's normally distributed... etc.)

Comment: Waiting times are often modeled as being exponentially distributed. Under this assumption $P(X \leq m)=\int_0^m \frac{1}{m} e^{-t/m} dt = 1-e^{-1}>1/2$.

Comment: @Ian - assuming exponentially distributed waiting times, the most likely value (i.e. the mode) is $0$.

Comment: Yes, but in the body of the question they speak of comparing <10 minutes to >10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the question is concerned with whether the distribution has a median which is higher or lower than the expected value. As mentioned by Ian: if we make the typical assumption that the waiting times are exponentially distributed, the median is smaller than the mean. If the waiting times are normally distributed, the median is equal to the mean. If the waiting times follow some heavy-tailed distribution, say the Pareto distribution, the median could be smaller than the mean.

Comment: Typo: the last "smaller" should be "larger".

Comment: Please explain yourself or provide an example, Ian. If you are not convinced by my example, you could also look at the log-normal distribution.

Heavy-tailed distributions have the intuitive interpretation, that a sum of independent outcomes is solely determined by the largest value. Thus the average is larger than most of the outcomes.

Comment: Well then I don't think it really makes your point, because the exponential is not heavy-tailed and its median is smaller than its mean as well.

Comment: I wanted to give some different examples. Heavy-tailed distributions are to my knowledge used increasingly in matters such as these, so they provide a good example to study. Maybe I could also have provided an example for the case median greater than mean.